# Permission Error in SSRS 2016

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am trying to create a data-source in `sql server 2016 report manager.` But I am getting below error.

[image]

I have checked the Site Settings. Logged User has `system administrator` privileges. I also checked `folder settings` and the Logged Server all the permissions ( `Content Manger, browser,etc..`). I am using Internet Explorer. Could some one help me to identity the root cause of this error?

Comment: Can you run IE as administrator?

Comment: Yes I am running IE as adminstrator

Comment: If the current user (shown top right in the web portal is in the system administrator role (it sounds like it is but just double check). Then check permissions to the ReportServer database via SSMS.

Comment: The current user is having Db_Owner permission to Report Server Database